# Problemas para fazer conexão serial Arduino com PHP

Tags: php, c++, arduino

Estou tentando fazer um termômetro com PHP, no Windows 10, e estou capturando os dados através de um Arduino com o código:

```
#include <OneWire.h>

#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Conectar o pino central dos sensores ao pino 10 do Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 10

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DeviceAddress thermometerOne = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x72, 0xC0, 0x62, 0x15, 0x01, 0x38 };
DeviceAddress thermometerTwo = { 0x28, 0xFF, 0xFA, 0x65, 0x72, 0x15, 0x02, 0x4D };

void setup(void)
{
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Start up the library
  sensors.begin();
  // set the resolution to 10 bit (good enough?)
  sensors.setResolution(thermometerOne, 12);
  sensors.setResolution(thermometerTwo, 12);
}

void getTemp(){
  printTemperature(thermometerOne);
  Serial.print(" ");
  printTemperature(thermometerTwo);
}

void printTemperature(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{ 
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
  if (tempC == -127.00) 
  {
    Serial.print("Erro");
  } 
  else 
  {
    Serial.print(tempC, 4);
  }
}

void IDFuncao(String funcao){
 if (funcao == String("temp")){
  getTemp(); 
 }
}

void decodificaMensagem(String mensagem){
  int i;
  String funcao = "";
  for (i=1; i<=4; i++){
    funcao = funcao + String(mensagem[i]);
  }
  IDFuncao(funcao);
}

void loop(void)
{ 
  //Verificando se tem algo na Porta
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    String mensagem = Serial.readString();
    String inicio = String(mensagem[0]);

    //Verificando se o que eu recebi começa com #
    if (inicio == String("#")){
      decodificaMensagem(mensagem);
    }
  }
}
```

Já pesqusei várias formas de captar os dados no PHP como este, usando phpserial:
[PhP Serial](https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial)

```
include 'PhpSerial.php';

$serial = new PhpSerial;

$serial->deviceSet("COM5");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");    

$serial->deviceOpen();

sleep (1);
$serial->sendMessage("#");

global $ler_serial;
$ler_serial = $serial->readPort();

$serial->deviceClose();
```

porém, recebo esse mensagem:

> Warning: Unable to open the device [...]

E fazendo:

```
$port = "COM5";
$fp = fopen($port, "r+b");
//sleep(1);
fwrite($fp,'#');
print_r($fp);
print_r(fgets($fp));
fclose($fp);
```

recebo:

> Warning: fopen(COM5): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Um amigo meu que fez o código do Arduino, ele disse que eu precisava mandar um '#' para o Arduino, como se fosse um protocolo, mandando o '#', ou não, o resultado é o mesmo.

O que posso fazer para receber as temperaturas captadas pelo Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

Isto parece indicar apenas que a porta COM5 **não é** a porta correta, ou esta desligada, para checar a porta correta abra o gerenciador de drivers, então vá até `COM & LPT` Deve aparecer algo como:

> [image: porta]

Se não aparecer nada em `Portas (COM & LPT)` (ou `Ports COM & LPT` em sistemas em inglês) significa que há algum problema na conexão do equipamento e talvez ele esteja em *outros dispositivos*, veja se existe algo lá com um simbolo de exclação em um ícone amarelo, como por exemplo:

> [image: falha]

Isto significa que falta algum driver no seu sistema, ou que existe alguma falha no hardware.

Se estiver em Ports/Portas e estiver funcionando normalmente, **mas não** é exibido a porta entre `(COM ...)` então basta clicar com o direito do Mouse/Rato nele e clicar em Propriedades/Properties

> [image: propriedades]

Se estiver tudo correto e não houver nenhum icone amarelo com exclamação então você pode efetuar o teste da porta usando softwares como `Hyperterminal`, no entanto este software parece não existir para Windows10 (talvez exista em windows-server), como alternativa pode baixar o:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/hypeterminal/

Abra o programa e clique em `Set Up` > `Port Configuration`, ou simplesmente aperte `Alt+C`, irá abrir esta janela:

[image: port]

Observe no combox **Port:**, veja se aparece a porta `COM5`, se não aparecer é porque não esta conectado, se aparecer selecione ela e clique no botão ao lado chamado `Connect`, se ocorrer qualquer erro é algum problema no Hardware ou problema na configuração do mesmo.

Comment: Está aparecendo normalmente "Dispositivo Serial USB (COM 5)". Esse hardware era usado em um outro programa (junto com o mesmo código do Arduíno que coloquei aqui)

Comment: @Matheus tem certeza que ele é o Arduino? Faça o seguinte abra a o CMD e digite isto: `mode com5:9600,n,8,1`

Comment: "Nome de dispositivo incorreto - COM5". Bom, tenho certeza que é Arduino, pois, aqui a gente só usa Arduinos para hardware.

Comment: @Matheus não tem nenhuma exclamação em amarelo em cima do icone do Arduino no Gerenciador de Drivers?

Comment: Não, [print](http://prntscr.com/ghw0ya), [Cmd](http://prntscr.com/ghw1um)

Comment: @Matheus editei a resposta e coloquei um passo-a-passo para você seguir de como testar a porta com o Hype! Terminal (Serial Port CommPort)

Comment: Baixei e [testei](http://prntscr.com/ghw54d), não recebi nenhum valor de retorno, mas consegui conectar normalmente. O que você está achando que pode ser ?

Comment: @Matheus tente assim `fopen('\\.com5', 'r+b');`

Comment: "Warning: fopen(\.COM5): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" Ali está aparecendo uma contra-barra, mas eu coloquei duas no fopen.

Comment: @Matheus abra o Hype! Terminal, vá em Setup e selecione a porta COM5, clique em connect e então feche a janela  de setup, na janela principal, veja aonde esta escrito command:, digite algo lá e tente e clique em "Send".

Comment: @Matheus você escreveu `\\.com5` ou `\\.COM5`?

Comment: Tentei das duas formas, também tentei até com umas contra-barras extras. O resultado era o mesmo.

Comment: @Matheus o teu servidor PHP esta na mesma máquina que está instalado o Arduino?

Comment: Sim, estou usando um servidor local [usbwebserver](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/)

Comment: @Matheus vou tentar conseguir um equipamento para efetuar testes e lhe aviso assim que conseguir.